# Maven GWT Plugin + JDO + MySQl

Tags: java, mysql, gwt, jdo, gwt-maven-plugin

I am creating `GWT project` using [gwt-maven-plugin with archetype.](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html)

Configure `JDO` using [datanucleus with jdo.](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/maven.html)

and adding `Mysql` dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.25</version>
</dependency>
```

but i am not able to create instance of PersistenceManagerFactory.

My datanucleus.properties is under project base directory.

```
javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass=org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory

datanucleus.autoCreateSchema=true
datanucleus.validateTables=false
datanucleus.validateConstraints=false
datanucleus.query.sql.allowAll = true

javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydatabase
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=root
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=xxxx
javax.jdo.option.Mapping=hsql
```

pom.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject-project</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.5.1</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
      <version>[3.2.0, 3.2.99)</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
      <version>[3.2.0, 3.2.99)</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
      <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
      <version>[3.2.0, 3.2.99)</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>i18n</goal>
              <goal>generateAsync</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see 
          gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
        <configuration>
          <modules>
            <module>com.myproject.MyProject</module>
          </modules>
          <runTarget>MyProject.html</runTarget>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
          <i18nMessagesBundle>com.myproject.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-release</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <!-- Force the enhancer to use the same version 
                    of core that's already on the classpath -->
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0-release</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
            <fork>false</fork>
            <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>enhance</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Trying to create instance of PersistenceManagerFactory.

```
PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("datanucleus.properties");
```

It will throw following exception.

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:528)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:781)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1083)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at com.dayris.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure that you have put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1158)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:360)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:768)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution.**

Getting this error because maven dependencies not copied to `WEB-INF/lib`. so it will not find at jars while running project in development mode when you make war file it will copy dependencies to `WEB-INF/lib`.

I just copied jars to `WEB-INF/lib` while working in development mode.

Still not satisfied with solution. Is there any other solution?